# Backbone hash based navigation and jqm

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I've got the following routes:

```
routes: {
        "home": "login",
        "login": "login",
        "forum": "forum",           
        "group/:id/:group": "group",
        "": "login",
}
```

if i'm on page forum the URL is url.com/#forum, but if I navigate from the forum view to the group view with:

```
router.navigate("group/:123/:nicegroup", {trigger: true});
```

1. problem: then the url changes to "url.com/group/123/nicegroup". In the meantime the "" route will be called because there is no "#" I think and the empty route "" fires. I end up on the login page.
2. problem: if I delete the "" route, then navigating from #forum to page group with:

   router.navigate("group/:123/:nicegroup", {trigger: true});

the url changes to url.com/group/123/nicegroup without the # in front of group. It works fine, but if I go back pushing the browser's back button, the url changes to url.com/#forum again and nothing happens. I still stay on the group page and I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:3791
$.extend.resetUIKeys jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:3791
$.extend.hashValueAfterReset jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:3803
$.extend.onPopState jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:3863
jQuery.event.dispatch require-jquery.js:5385
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Again, in the second problem I already deleted the "" route, so that it doesn't bother me but it's still my 1st problem.

I disabled all jqm navigation.

```
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```

Comment: are you including the colons in the route that you're calling with router.navigate()?

Comment: I know this isn't answering your question, but I have recently been down this route and eventually dumped the backbone routing and used https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router instead, which offered much bet compatibility with jqm - give it a quick look before you invest to much time in the backbone routing option

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a while ago - but have you enabled [Backbone.History](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) when your application starts?

```
Backbone.history.start()
```

Comment: Yes, I have. I now use ?param=:param to pass through paramenters